# Медиана уникальных элементов вектора

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дан вектор `std::vector<std::size_t>`. Как наиболее эффективно получить медиану **уникальных** элементов вектора? Например, для вектора `1,6,3,1,5,1,2` -> `1,2,3,5,6` -> `3`

На ум приходит только решение с копированием элементов вектора в `std::set<std::size_t>` и взятие цетрального элемента, но итератор не даёт сделать это за константу.

Comment: Ecли вектор изменяемый - то можно отсортировать и удалить дубликаты.

Comment: @VTT да, но если удаление дубликатов за N, то это будет дальше дольше, чем с сетом, там N / 2

Comment: У `set` вставка за O(log N)...

Comment: @Harry да, получится тогда N*log N + N / 2 с сетом

Comment: @Harry медианы ищутся в большом цикле, поэтому важно N или N/2

Answer (score 1):

За константу вряд ли у вас что получится. Как я понимаю, вектор уже отсортирован? тогда

```
v[(unique(v.begin(),v.end())-v.begin())/2]
```

за O(N)

Если вектор не отсортирован - то еще и сортировка; итого O(N log N)

Если четко известен диапазон значений и он небольшой - то блочная сортировка спасает - опять до O(N)

Comment: нет, вектор не отсортирован, я поменял пример, чтобы не вводить в заблуждение

Comment: можно про блочную сортировку подробней?

Comment: До просто если, скажем, у вас все числа до 10 - берем массив из 10 элементов. В вашем случае достаточно просто `bool`, и отмечать те элементы, которые есть, как `true`. Дальше собираем только те, у которых элемент равен `true`, и находим медиану... Для 1,6,3,1,5,1,2 имеем `true` в элементах с индексами 1,2,3,5,6 - так что находим 3.